# How to save dynamic changes to a Silverlight XAML file?

Tags: xaml, silverlight

In a scenario where the user created a textbox in the xaml page during runtime, I need to save his changes to the design of the XAML so that it is available when he opens it the next time.

I understand that XAMLWriter is only available for WPF, is there a way to do this in Silverlight ?

Comment: There are many different ways to save data, but we do *not* save data into the application files. You could store it in a database, a text file, a settings file, a configuration file, but *not* the application file.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to save the XAML to a text file during runtime ?

Comment: I can tell that you're still confused. We *don't* save the XAML... why save the controls? You just need the *data elememts*, not the *UI elements*. The UI will be re-rendered each time you run the application, so there is no point in saving that.

Comment: I think I haven't explained myself well enough. I need to save the UI elements because the user does changes to the UI in runtime. For example, he can add new textboxes and checkboxes to create the design the suits him. So I need to save the UI elements not just the content in the UI.

Comment: You mean that the two sentences in you question didn't explain your problem well enough?? What a surprise.