# How to save controls added in runtime to a Silverlight page?

Tags: xaml, silverlight

My silverlight application allows the user to adjust the design of the page as he wants, so he can add, edit or delete controls from it during runtime. When he closes the application and opens it again, all his changes are gone. How can I save these changes to the page design so that they appear to him next time he opens the application ?

Comment: You can save those user decisions into the `Isolated Starage` and try to read from there whenever the application is opened.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save dynamic changes to a Silverlight XAML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973426/how-to-save-dynamic-changes-to-a-silverlight-xaml-file)

Comment: Well, that was mine too. I just wanted to put the question in a better way. The other question wasn't answered.

Comment: You need to use something along the lines of a Command pattern. Essentially when the user adds a new control to the UI, u would create a command which describes what the user did. You would store the commands in a List or a Stack as they are being executed. Once the user leaves the page you'd save the contents of that list to isolated storage,web service or whatever. Finally, when the page is loaded the first thing you'd do is to retrieve the serialized list from storage, & 4 each command recreate the ui so it looks the same as they left it. http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern

Comment: ***Note that is not to be confused with the ICommand interface and implementations.